# understanding uibutton target self superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

Can someone please explain to me the uibutton target functionality from this example:

I have a ViewController. I add a uiview with two buttons to this viewcontroller. One button is crated in the init and the other one is created by a method 'addSecondButton'. Both buttons have the same action on [self superview] target which is the ViewController. The code:

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MySpecialView *myspecialview = [[MySpecialView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:myspecialview];

    [myspecialview addSecondButton];
}

- (void)specialMethod { NSLog(@"right here!"); }
```

MySpecialView.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, frame.size.width, 50)];
        [button addTarget:[self superview] action:@selector(specialMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [self addSubview:button];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addSecondButton {
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 90, self.frame.size.width, 50)];
    [button addTarget:[self superview] action:@selector(specialMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self addSubview:button];
}
```

So when tapping the blue button which is created in the init, specialMethod does execute. When pressing the red one which is added after the init, the app crashes with the warning - unknow selector for uiview.

What I really don't understand is when I NSLog [self superview] in the init, it is null, because the object is not yet created and returned to the superview, but the action does get executed for some reason.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure that the action for blue button gets executed? It shouldn't as the target which you added is `nil`.

Comment: 100% sure. create a project, paste the code and try for yourself. strange stuff he...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have indeed added a `nil` target for the blue button in `initWithFrameMethod`. According to the Apple's [Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW1), when you add a `nil` target, the message (`specialMethod` in your case) will be passed through the responder chain:

```
When the user manipulates a control, such as a button or switch, and the target for the action method is nil, the message is sent through a chain of responders starting with the control view.
```

As your `ViewController` is a part of the responder chain, it will receive this message and call its `specialMethod`.

Comment: I think this is an interesting case... can someone tell _why_ `[self superview]` is `nil` when it is used as _target_ in `initWithFrame:`? The view controller's view should have been instantiated at that point in time, since `MySpecialView` is created in the view controller's `viewDidLoad`

Comment: `initWithFrame` is called before `MySpecialView is added as a subview to the controller's view.

Comment: ah sorry, of course it's nil because the view has not yet been added to the view controller's view!

Comment: @nburk, because you first create the object which you want to add (in this case uiview) and only when the return self happens, it is added to the superview.

Answer (score 2):

`[self superview]` is a pointer to ViewController's view, not ViewController itself.  The selector you are defining as the action for the button should target the instance of ViewController, not the ViewController's view since you have the method `specialMethod` defined in ViewController.  If you really wanted to use `[self superview]` as the target for the action, then you'll need to subclass UIView, implement `specialMethod` and set that new UIView subclass as the view of the view controller (not a subview).  This way, `[self superview]` will refer to a class that actually has the selector specified on the target.

I didn't actually try your code sample, but it's so obviously wrong, if it does work, it's coincidence and shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: well explained! you need to make sure that your `target` is not the view controller's view but the view controller itself! however, it sounds like for your situation the `delegate` pattern is more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your message. I know if I add something like a mainview en put a view on top of it, the [self superview] would work. I came this across when I downloaded an example project for something else and was surprised that it worked. So my goal is not to help me with the communication between uiviews, I know how that works, but I wanted to understand how the action reached the ViewController and executes the method.